# Yii2 subdirectories workaround?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, namespaces, yii2-basic-app

I'm having trouble autoloading PHP classes in the Yii2 "app" namespace.

For example, my project looks like so:

```
yii2
    -Controllers ( app\controllers )
        -SomeController.php
        -SomeOtherController.php
    -Services ( app\services )
        -Service1.php
        -Service2.php
```

I want to move Service2.php into a subdirectory in the "Services" folder to look like this:

```
Services ( app\services )
    -Service1.php 
    GlobalServices ( app\services\GlobalServices )
        -Service2.php
```

Apparently Yii2 autoloading does not support this at this time. I need to implement a workaround to make this work. I have ~30 services at this time so having them all in one "Services" folder is very disorganized.

I'm attempting to avoid doing any dirty solution of creating a "GlobalService.php" file and then including all of the other services within that file. Instead I would rather use conventional namespacing and autoloading.

Answer (score 0):

Try this by rename folder name GlobalServices to globalServices (app\services\globalServices)